# JavaFX: Window closing event prevents button action

Tags: button, popup, javafx, focus

I did implement a popup window in a new stage and I'm now trying to close it, no matter where I click (excluding the popup itself). This works just fine. Although the popup windows disappears when I click on another element (e.g. a button) on the background, I'd still like to get the event for the button. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I put together a short example of the situation.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // the popup
            Pane p = new Pane();
            p.setPrefSize(100, 100);
            p.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #660066");
            final Stage popUp = new Stage();
            Scene popUpScene = new Scene(p);

            popUp.setScene(popUpScene);

            Button btnShow = new Button("Show popUp");
            root.setCenter(btnShow);
            btnShow.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    ChangeListener stageFocusListener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                            if (!newPropertyValue) {
                                popUp.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    popUp.focusedProperty().addListener(stageFocusListener);
                    popUp.show();

                }
            });

            Button btnTest = new Button("test");
            root.setRight(btnTest);
            btnTest.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    System.out.println("Button test clicked");
                }
            });

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the hiding event to the queue without disturbing the event handling procedure of the button

```
if (!newPropertyValue) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            popUp.hide();
        }
    });
}
```